# How do I return list of queues in Best practical Request tracker?

Tags: rest, rt

I need our ticket system Request tracker from Best practical to search for all queues and return list of them. They could change and I do not want to hardcode them in source code or config files.

Is there search query for it?

```
search/queue?query=...
```

gives

```
RT/4.0.7 500 Server Error
Unsupported object type.
```

Or how can I modify ticket system to return list of all queues?

Ticket system:
http://bestpractical.com/rt/

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

`REST/1.0/search/queue` exists in newer RT releases (4.2.2 and later).

Answer (score 2):

The following links are working in 4.4.0.

1. Lists all users:  `/REST/1.0/search/user?query=`
2. Lists all groups: `/REST/1.0/search/group?query=`
3. Lists all queues: `/REST/1.0/search/queue?query=`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the query you are looking for is not available in the RT REST api.  From a similar question on the RT Users list:

> RT's REST API is intended mostly for working with tickets (the query
>   is actually TicketSQL as available in the normal Query Builder UI).
>
> If you need to work with and modify other RT objects, you'll want to
>   use RT's perl API.

http://lists.bestpractical.com/pipermail/rt-users/2011-October/073272.html

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote, you can use the RT [REST1 API](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST) or it's newer version ([REST2 API](https://github.com/bestpractical/rt-extension-rest2/blob/master/README)). But it needs some configuration before. Then something like

```
https://your_rt_server/REST/1.0/search/queue?query=
https://your_rt_server/REST/2.0/queues/all
```

should work.

Perhaps more straight-forward way is to use the [PERL API](https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/4.2.16/index.html) if you have the access to the filesystem of the RT server. Then it should work like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use lib ("/opt/rt4/lib");
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use RT -init;

my $queues = RT::Queues->new($RT::SystemUser);
$queues->UnLimit;
while (my $queue = $queues->Next){
   say $queue->Name;
}
```